# Protools- Dv toolkit2

Tags: film-sound-design

I’m using Protools 8 with DV Toolkit 2.
If I upgrade to Protools 10 do I need a DV toolkit as well or is everything included?

Answer (score 1):

There is no DV Toolkit anymore...most of the functionality from it has been incorporated into 10 already. There is only the Complete Production Toolkit now, which you can update to from DVTK2. If you upgrade, CPTK costs $800 instead of $2000. I'd suggest you [take a look at what the CPTK provides](http://shop.avid.com/store/product.do?product=307048795257792), then decide if you need that extra functionality or not.

[This page](http://www.avid.com/US/products/Complete-Production-Toolkit/features) might actually provide more useful information, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Surround tracks then DV Tool Kit becomes redundant. If you do need surround then take the upgrade option from DV Toolkit to Complete Production Toolkit for $800. But with PT10 you no longer need DigTranslator, you will get the Timecode ruler - ie the things you paid for when you got DV Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you loose the DVTK2 ability to perform automation snapshots and in order to unlock that in 10 you need CPTK.